# How to know, who made request in a Web Api?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I want to prevent that other people make a request to my Web API. I have a page(www.PageAuthorized.com) that makes a request to some webs API but it's possible that someone makes other to the same APIs.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit ? Give us more details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that configuring CORS for your webapi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://mydomain.xyz"/> />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

then only calls from mydomain.xyz will be allowed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: It resolves my problems :), Now I can restrict the request from specifics WebClient. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options here. You can implement some certificate check. Or you introduce a token that must be send and verified. You can also use username and password or today it would be better to use oauth. Or just simply base authorization over https. Cookie and maybe some other option as well. Depends how complex and secure you want to do it and how many users it will be used. Try to provide more details about your application